# Getting this error - System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: apex

I am getting the above error while I am trying to run the below code using developer console.

=========================================================

This is my apex class

```
public class JSON2Apex{

public static list<JSON2Apex> parse(String content) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Whizleads_Personality_Analyser/v3/profile?version=2016-10-20&consumption_preferences=true&raw_scores=true');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(stringToJSON(content));
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            system.debug(res.getBody());
        return (list<JSON2Apex>) System.JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), list<JSON2Apex>.class);
    }

    private static String stringToJSON(String content) {

                List<ContentItemsJSON.contentItem> contentItems =  new List<ContentItemsJSON.contentItem>();
            ContentItemsJSON.contentItem contentItem = new ContentItemsJSON.contentItem();
            contentItem.id = '1234567';
            contentItem.userid = content;
            contentItem.sourceid = 'twitter';
            contentItem.created = (Integer)Datetime.now().getTime();
            contentItem.updated = (Integer)Datetime.now().getTime();
            contentItem.contenttype = 'text/plain';
            contentItem.charset = 'UTF-8';
            contentItem.language = 'en-us';
            contentItem.content = content;
            contentItem.parentid = '';
            contentItem.reply = false;
            contentItem.forward = false;
            contentItems.add(contentItem);


        JSONGenerator generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeObjectField('contentItems', contentItems);
        generator.writeEndObject();
        return generator.getAsString();
    }

    public class Consumption_preferences {
        public String consumption_preference_id;
        public String name;
        public Integer score;
    }

    public Integer word_count;
    public String processed_language;
    public List<Personality> personality;
    public List<Children> needs;
    public List<Children> values;
    public List<Behavior> behavior;
    public List<Consumption_preferences_Z> consumption_preferences;
    public List<Warnings> warnings;

    public class Consumption_preferences_Z {
        public String consumption_preference_category_id;
        public String name;
        public List<Consumption_preferences> consumption_preferences;
    }

    public class Personality {
        public String trait_id;
        public String name;
        public String category;
        public Double percentile;
        public Double raw_score;
        public Boolean significant;
        public List<Children> children;
    }

    public class Children {
        public String trait_id;
        public String name;
        public String category;
        public Double percentile;
        public Double raw_score;
        public Boolean significant;
    }

    public class Behavior {
        public String trait_id;
        public String name;
        public String category;
        public Double percentage;
    }

    public class Warnings {
    }

}
```

==================================================================

I am calling the method using developer console

```
JSON2Apex.parse('The story centers around Deanna Lambert a teen troubled by social exile and branding rumors. When she was thirteen her father caught her and her brothers friend, seventeen year old Tommy Webber, having unprotected sex in the back of Tommys Buick. Word gets around by Tommy, and Deanna is named the school slut. Her father becomes distant and cold towards her, never showing any affection after what he witnessed. Three years later, Deanna still lives in her small hometown of Pacifica, California. Her affair with Tommy Webber is still a popular gossip topic and her older brother, Darren, and his girlfriend, Stacy, now live in their basement with their child, April. Keeping a fantasy of moving out of the house with Darren, April and Stacy in her mind and coming to a happy home, Deanna gets a summer job at a ratty pizza parlor, Picassos Pizza, while also dealing with inhibited feelings of affection for her best friend, Jason, who is dating her other friend, Lee. As the summer progresses, Deannas secret love of Jason deepens. She begins to become more and more envious of Lee, especially of Lees happy home and inner peace. One day, Deanna finds that Stacy fled the house, leaving April behind, and does not return. At the same time, she develops a friendship with her boss at Picassos, Michael, while working alongside Tommy Webber. One evening, Michael gives Deanna a ride home from work and Deannas father grows suspicious of Michaels motives. Deanna then lashes out at her father for never again trusting her after he caught Deanna and Tommy in the car, which causes her father to temporarily leavem');
```

ContentJSON Class

public class ContentItemsJSON{

```
public List<ContentItem> contentItems;

public class ContentItem {
    public String id;   //245160944223793152
    public String userid;   //bob
    public String sourceid; //twitter
    public Integer created; //1427720427
    public Integer updated; //1427720427
    public String contenttype;  //text/plain
    public String charset;  //UTF-8
    public String language; //en-us
    public String content;  //This is a sample tweet
    public String parentid; //
    public boolean reply;
    public boolean forward;

}

public static ContentItemsJSON parse(String json){
    return (ContentItemsJSON) System.JSON.deserialize(json, ContentItemsJSON.class);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Your example string is not valid JSON, which is presumably why it's failing. What exactly are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to include any relevant context so we can further assist you.

Comment: I am trying to implement IBM watson profile API. Do you have a code for it or can you help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this part of your code:

```
JSONGenerator generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
generator.writeStartObject();
generator.writeObjectField('contentItems', contentItems);
generator.writeEndObject();
```

You are trying to add contentItems as Object.

Here is the example how you can process it,  do not forget to use StartArray and EndArray (http://salesforce-walker.blogspot.com/2013/08/json-generator.html):

```
gen.writeFieldName('attendees');
gen.writeStartArray();
//for each attendee create a JSON object
for(GoogleEventAttendee gEventAttendee : this.attendees){
     gen.writeStartObject();
     gen.writeStringField('email', gEventAttendee.email);            
     gen.writeBooleanField('optional', gEventAttendee.optional);
     gen.writeNumberField('additionalGuests', gEventAttendee.additionalGuests);
     gen.writeEndObject();
}
gen.writeEndArray();
```

UPDATE:

Here is how it goes with your code:

```
List<ContentItemsJSON.contentItem> contentItems = new List<ContentItemsJSON.contentItem>();
ContentItemsJSON.contentItem contentItem = new ContentItemsJSON.contentItem();
contentItem.id = '1234567';
contentItem.userid = content;
contentItem.sourceid = 'twitter';
contentItem.created = (Integer) Datetime.now().getTime();
contentItem.updated = (Integer) Datetime.now().getTime();
contentItem.contenttype = 'text/plain';
contentItem.charset = 'UTF-8';
contentItem.language = 'en-us';
contentItem.content = content;
contentItem.parentid = '';
contentItem.reply = false;
contentItem.forward = false;
contentItems.add(contentItem);


JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();

gen.writeFieldName('contentItems');
gen.writeStartArray();
for (ContentItemsJSON.contentItem item_i : contentItems) {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('id', item_i.id);
    gen.writeStringField('userid', item_i.userid);
    gen.writeStringField('sourceid', item_i.sourceid);
    gen.writeNumberField('created', item_i.created);
    gen.writeNumberField('updated', item_i.updated);
    gen.writeStringField('contenttype', item_i.contenttype);
    gen.writeStringField('parentid', item_i.parentid);
    gen.writeBooleanField('reply', item_i.reply);
    gen.writeBooleanField('forward', item_i.forward);

    gen.writeEndObject();
}
gen.writeEndArray();

gen.writeEndObject();
return gen.getAsString();
```

Comment: Can you modify my code using start and end array. 

I have added my contentjson class